# Unrecognized escape sequence in SqlConnection constructor

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

when ever I make connection it gives an error

> Unrecognized escape sequence.

```
NEPOLEON\ADMN HERE ON THIS SLASH. NEPOLEON\ADMN IS MY SQL SERVER NAME.

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=NEPOLEON\ADMN;Database=MASTER;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

Comment: nest time when you ask question fromat it proper to get proper answer and avoid negetive votes...its edited by me now..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Escape the \ character like :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=NEPOLEON\\ADMN;Database=MASTER;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

or

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=NEPOLEON\ADMN;Database=MASTER;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

Answer (score 8):

Try changing it to this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=NEPOLEON\\ADMN;Database=MASTER;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

or this

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=NEPOLEON\ADMN;Database=MASTER;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

In .NET you can escape special characters by either putting an `@` in front of the string or using a special value to represent the character you want to escape.  In this case you can use `\\` to represent a `\`