# How to insert data into SQL Server database by VB.Net in windows application

Tags: c#, php, vb.net, connection-string

How to insert data into SQL Server database by VB.Net in Windows application. I am using the Windows form application.
At run time it gives exception that:

> con.open() the connection is not established.

code:

```
imports system.data
imports system.data.sqlclient

on button_click(){

    Dim cn as SqlConnection=new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;InitialCatlog=shri;Security=True;User id=---;password=system")
    cn.close()
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd as SqlCommand=new SqlCommand("insert into tbl1 values('"&textbox1.Text&"','"textbox2.Text"')",cn)
    cmd.executeNonQuery()
    messageBox.Text="record Inserted"
    cn.close()
    ...
}
```

Where `tbl1` is the table in the database.

Comment: Do you use a `trusted connection` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are typos in your connection string.

- Replace "`Security`" with "`Integrated Security`".
- Also, there should be a space in "`Initial Catalog`".

Comment: but if it shows exception at run time that ,the connection was not establieshed  then  what should  i do?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot using of '& &' for this line

```
Dim cmd as SqlCommand=new SqlCommand("insert into tbl1 values('"& textbox1.Text &"','"& textbox2.Text &"')",cn)
```

or use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586083/unrecognized-escape-sequence-in-connection-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (a standard connection):

```
Password=system;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=---;Initial Catalog=shri;Data Source=.\sqlexpress
```

If you want your password saved in connection string for future uses of connection string of connection object set `Persist Security Info=True;`; other ways set it `Persist Security Info=False;`

Actualy when you set `Persist Security Info=False;`; The password of your connection string property of your connection object will hide.

Or If you use a trusted connection use this:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=shri;Data Source=.\sqlexpress
```

Then; Change your `sqlcommand` to run a stored procedure for inserting is recommended. But the better use of `insert into` is this:

```
insert into <table Name> (<List of Fileds>) Values (<List of Values>)
```

And be careful about type of values for adding (') in your command string.

Comment: I i didnt know the password of the sql server then what should  i write in the connection string .

Comment: I i didnt know the password of the sql server then what should  i write in the connection string .And also in case of the copying the string there is one attribute inside the sring   Pooling=false whether i should keep it or not

Comment: Ok!, so you used a trusted connection (Authenticate with windows), so I edit my answer. Use this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/)